# change text inside run time created textbox

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls

I need to create multiple of textboxs during run time after user trigger event thus I use loop to create textbox and put it inside arraylist to access later

```
for(*something)
{
   ArrayList List1 = new ArrayList();
   TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
   t1.Location = new Point(x, y);
   panelA.Controls.Add(t1);
   List1.Add(t1);
}
```

And I use this code below to access the text inside when user input(dunno if right way but it works) :-

```
List1[i - 1].ToString().Replace("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: ", "").Trim()
```

My problem is,how to **change** text inside textbox? I was looking for something like this:-

```
List1[i].Text="new string";
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
((TextBox)List1[i]).Text = "new string";
```

or use

```
List<TextBox> instead of ArrayList
```

Comment: LoL that easy?hahaha totally works, what a noob i am,thanks @Ondrej Svejdar :)